# Failed to start component Tomcat with mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I can run my Web spring-boot application in my IntelliJ, but failed with:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

My application boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({WebConfigurer.class})
@ComponentScan("com.ed.nlu.qe")
@PropertySource({"classpath:boot.properties", "classpath:important.properties", "classpath:jss.properties",
        "classpath:system.properties", "classpath:ump.properties"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JnluQEWebStart extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(NluWebStart.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring-boot version:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

Error messages:

```
2018-08-30 at 17:27:08.305 [main] INFO  org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [183] [log] - Starting service Tomcat
2018-08-30 at 17:27:08.307 [main] INFO  org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [183] [log] - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.61
2018-08-30 at 17:27:08.533 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [183] [log] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-30 at 17:27:08.533 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext [276] [prepareEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3320 ms
2018-08-30 at 17:27:08.960 [Tomcat-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [185] [log] - A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addFilter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Filter;)Ljavax/servlet/FilterRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.onStartup(AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.java:225) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean.onStartup(FilterRegistrationBean.java:42) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:229) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    ... 7 more

2018-08-30 at 17:27:08.964 [main] ERROR org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [185] [log] - A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:339) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.jd.jnlu.qe.boot.JnluQEWebStart.main(JnluQEWebStart.java:22) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at ...
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:339) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.61.jar:7.0.61]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    ... 14 more

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.jd.jnlu.qe.boot.JnluQEWebStart.main (JnluQEWebStart.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init> (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.jd.jnlu.qe.boot.JnluQEWebStart.main (JnluQEWebStart.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init> (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.jd.jnlu.qe.boot.JnluQEWebStart.main (JnluQEWebStart.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init> (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.jd.jnlu.qe.boot.JnluQEWebStart.main (JnluQEWebStart.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init> (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.jd.jnlu.qe.boot.JnluQEWebStart.main (JnluQEWebStart.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal (StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init> (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.jd.jnlu.qe.boot.JnluQEWebStart.main (JnluQEWebStart.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Comment: Why not use Tomcat7 Maven Plugin ?

Comment: How to use the Tomcat7 Maven plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [Tomcat7 Maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/) which can be use for version 7+

> The Tomcat7 Maven Plugin provides goals to manipulate WAR projects within the Tomcat servlet container version 7.x

Example from pom:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <url>http://<domain>:<port>/<appName></url>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You can use [goal](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) `tomcat7:run-war`:

> Runs the current project as a packaged web application using an embedded Tomcat server.

```
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8090/manager</url>
                <server>localhost</server>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                <!--<skipTests>true</skipTests>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

Comment: How to do "goal tomcat7:run-war"? The command not found when I executed it in terminal.

Comment: @user697911 you need to add tomcat7 plugin first

Answer (score 0):

Use this in maven to create the compiled file:

```
mvn clean package
```

And then use this code to run your java file:

```
java -jar YourJarFile.jar
```

Or if your using JSP with Spring boot you can do this if the above doesnt work:

```
java -jar target/YourJarFile.jar
```